# Missing argument in aws_config_remediation_configuration resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, aws-config

I'm using terraform aws provider version 3.9.0 and working on implementing a remediation for aws config rule. I'm not able to find an argument within "aws_config_remediation_configuration" resource which is related to Automatic trigger of the configured remediation. I see that the describe returns the attribute (automatic=true or automatic=false), but I am not finding a way to set it using terraform. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not yet supported. There is a github issue to add `automatic` to `aws_config_remediation_configuration`

- [aws_config_remediation_configuration: No support for "automatic" remediation](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/15491)

Comment: Thank you Marcin.

Comment: Note that this is now supported. It was released in v3.67.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider. Documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/config_remediation_configuration#automatic